# Error types - Message: unknown error

Tags: python, selenium, error-handling

After running  a scrapping code I have this error message that occurred when there is a blank text field

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown
>   error: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

In order to avoid this problem, I want to wrap it with try-catch block:

```
        try:
            valeur = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent;", valeur)
        except "put the error here":
            valeur = ""
```

What is the type error of this thing? Why can't I find it in the message error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

    try:
        valeur = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent;", valeur)
    except WebDriverException as e:
        print(e.message)
```